# object Collection Containing a List of IDs Linq

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a list box and the user is able to multi-select.  I want to use Linq and bring back the records of the selected IDs that the user selects.  I need to bring back the full object record for each selected ID

Here is the contact object along with collection object

```
 Namespace MODEL
     <System.Serializable()> _
     Public Class ContactCollection
         Inherits System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of Contact)
         Implements IList(Of Contact)
     End Class
 End Namespace


 Namespace MODEL
     <System.Serializable()> _
     Public Class Contact

         Private mContactID As Int32 = 0
         Private mFirstName As String
         Private mLastName As String

         Public Property ContactID As Int32
             Get
                 Return mContactID
             End Get
             Set(value As Int32)
                 mContactID = value
             End Set
         End Property

         Public Property FirstName As String
             Get
                 Return mFirstName
             End Get
             Set(value As String)
                 mFirstName = value
             End Set
         End Property

         Public Property LastName As String
             Get
                 Return mLastName
             End Get
             Set(value As String)
                 mLastName = value
             End Set
         End Property

     End Class
 End Namespace
```

Adding 5 Records to the collection object

```
            Dim objCollection As New MODEL.ContactCollection
            Dim obj As New MODEL.Contact

            objCollection.Add(New MODEL.Contact With {
            .ContactID = 1, _
            .FirstName = "John", _
            .LastName = "Smtih" _
            })

            objCollection.Add(New MODEL.Contact With {
            .ContactID = 2, _
            .FirstName = "Mark", _
            .LastName = "Davis" _
            })

            objCollection.Add(New MODEL.Contact With {
            .ContactID = 3, _
            .FirstName = "Tom", _
            .LastName = "Howe" _
            })

            objCollection.Add(New MODEL.Contact With {
            .ContactID = 4, _
            .FirstName = "Jerry", _
            .LastName = "Thomas" _
            })

            objCollection.Add(New MODEL.Contact With {
            .ContactID = 5, _
            .FirstName = "Jane", _
            .LastName = "Marry" _
            })
```

This is the selected contact List from the list box

```
            Dim lstContacts As New List(Of Integer)
            lstContacts.Add(2)
            lstContacts.Add(4)
```

I am not sure what to do at this point with Linq to find the values.  I think I have to use contains but I have tried may different ways but I was unable to get the values.

I have tried this Linq but does not work or bring any records back

```
 Dim objSearch from SearchContacts in objCollection
        Where (lstContacts.Contains(SearchContacts.ContactID))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Ids, try that :

```
Dim ids As IEnumerable(Of Int32) = myListBox.SelectedItems _
                                    .OfType(Of Contact)() _
                                    .Select( Function(c) c.ContactID ) _
```

**Edit**

If you want the Contacts,  you can just just :

```
Dim ids As IEnumerable(Of Contact) = myListBox.SelectedItems _
                                    .OfType(Of Contact)()
```

And if you want the contacts in a separate copied collection, you can :

```
Dim ids As List(Of Contact) = myListBox.SelectedItems _
                                    .OfType(Of Contact)() _
                                    .ToList()
```

Last (if think this is your real question - just tell and I erase everything above)

```
Dim selectedContacts As IEnumerable(Of MODEL.Contact) = From contact In objCollection
                                                           Join id In lstContacts
                                                           On contact.ContactID Equals id
                                                           Select contact
```

Comment: I don't want just the ids I want the full record within the collection.  The records who's ids are selected.

Comment: I am just reading your question again, and ... should I understand that you listbox displays only the IDs, not the full contact ?